# Firebase: Contar ramas o atributos en un BD

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo un BD Firebase.  En cada rama tengo hijos que pueden ser atributos/valor `Nombre: "nombre1"` y también Subhijos creados con un `push()`.

Ejemplo de la BD:

```
Empresa
    Nivel-1
       -LyLwTc7H9RxTDiEtnt2
       -LyM1FFRooGX9Xa33Etx
       Nombre: "nombre1"
```

Lo que necesito es obtener cuantos Subhijos tiene `Nivel-1` pero sin contar `Nombre: "nombre1"`.  En este ejemplo me devería devolver `2`.

He probado con `getChildrenCount` pero me devuelve `3`.

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Revisa la forma en que estas guardando los datos, se ve muy raro que en una lista de keys autogeneradas derrepente aparezca un campo "Nombre". No conozco tu estructura de datos, pero es bastante poco comun y quizas te pueda traer problemas mas graves. Por lo general no deberias mezclar distintos tipos de datos en una lista.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No puedo ver tu código completo pero por lo que me dices se solucionaría de la forma robusta poniendo un -1 en tu método

```
int cantidadDeSubhijos = padre.getChildrenCount() -1;
```

Solo que adaptado a lo que tengas en tu código